# Javascript массив

Tags: javascript

Помогите сделать вывод и правильно вписать массив.
Вот задание:
 Дан массив целых чисел.Найти порядковый номер наибольшего по значению числа, являющегося симметричным в десятичном представлении.

```
int N = mas1.nextInt(); 
int mas[] = new int[N]; 
int c[]; 
//заполнение массива 
for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) { 
mas[i] = mas1.nextInt(); 
} 
int a; 
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) { 
c[i] = 0; 
} 
int max = 0; 
int imax = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) { 
a = mas[i]; 
int j = 0; 
while (a > 0) { 
c[j] = a % 10; 
a /= 10; 
j++; 
} 
int kr = 1; 
for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) { 
if (c[k] != c[j-k+1]) { 
kr = 0; 
break; 
} 
} 
if (kr == 1 && (a > max || max == 0)) { 
max = a; 
imax = i; 
}
```

вот я переделал:

```
var mas[] = [10, 11, 5, 1441];
var c[];
var max = 0;
var imax = 0;
var a;
var i = 0;
var k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
  a = mas[i];
  var j = 0;
  while (a > 0) {
    c[j] = a % 10;
    a /= 10;
    j++;
  }
  var kr = 1;
  for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
    if (c[k] != c[j - k + 1]) {
      kr = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (kr == 1 && (a > max || max == 0)) {
    max = a;
    imax = i;
  }
```

Comment: `mas1.nextInt()` - что есть `mas1`?

Comment: а речь точно по [tag:javascript] а не про [tag:java]?

Comment: java script точно

Comment: - Да или нет?   - Или!

Comment: Игорь это java script

Comment: @Алещка13 В языке javascript (без пробела) нет такого: `new int[N];` Что за код Вы выложили?

Comment: игорь посмотрите я переделал код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Не ответ.** Вот Вам, отлаживайте:

```js
function FindMaxPalindrome(mas) {
  var max = 0;
  var imax = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    var a = mas[i];
    var j = 0;
    var c = [];
    while (a > 0) {
      c[j] = a % 10;
      a /= 10;
      j++;
    }
    var kr = 1;
    for (var k = 0; k < j; k++) {
      if (c[k] != c[j - k + 1]) {
        kr = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (kr == 1 && (a > max || max == 0)) {
      max = a;
      imax = i;
    }
  }
  return imax;
}

var mas1 = [10, 11, 5, 1441];
var index = FindMaxPalindrome(mas1);
console.log(index + " - " + mas1[index]);
```

И работающий вариант:

```js
function FindMaxPalindrome(mas) {
  var max = 0;
  var imax = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    var a = mas[i];
    var j = 0;
    var c = [];
    while (a > 0.5) {
      c[j] = a % 10;
      a = (a - c[j]) / 10;
      j++;
    }
    console.log(c);
    var kr = 1;
    for (var k = 0; k < j; k++) {
      if (c[k] != c[j - k - 1]) {
        kr = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (kr == 1 && (a > max || max == 0)) {
      max = a;
      imax = i;
    }
  }
  return imax;
}

var mas1 = [10, 11, 5, 1441];
var index = FindMaxPalindrome(mas1);
console.log(index + " - " + mas1[index]);
```

Comment: игорь спасибо вы лучший

Comment: @Алещка13 Рад был помочь. Успехов!